# Initializing H2O in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

When trying to initialize H2O in Python by running the lines:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
```

I getting the exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/workspace/DataScience/univariate_analysis/prudential_RF.py", line 4, in 
    h2o.init()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o.py", line 668, in init
    H2OConnection(ip=ip, port=port,start_h2o=start_h2o,enable_assertions=enable_assertions,license=license,max_mem_size_GB=max_mem_size_GB,min_mem_size_GB=min_mem_size_GB,ice_root=ice_root,strict_version_check=strict_version_check)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.py", line 101, in __init__
    raise EnvironmentError, message
EnvironmentError: Version mismatch. H2O is version 3.2.0.9, but the python package is version 3.6.0.8.
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.py", line 565, in end_session
    H2OConnection.delete(url_suffix="InitID")
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.py", line 393, in delete
    return __H2OCONN__._do_raw_rest(url_suffix, "DELETE", None, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.py", line 483, in _do_raw_rest
    .format(http_result.status_code,http_result.reason,method,url,detailed_error_msgs))
EnvironmentError: h2o-py got an unexpected HTTP status code:
 404 Not Found (method = DELETE; url = http://localhost:54321/3/InitID). 
detailed error messages: DELETE /3/InitID not found
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.py", line 565, in end_session
    H2OConnection.delete(url_suffix="InitID")
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.py", line 393, in delete
    return __H2OCONN__._do_raw_rest(url_suffix, "DELETE", None, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.py", line 483, in _do_raw_rest
    .format(http_result.status_code,http_result.reason,method,url,detailed_error_msgs))
EnvironmentError: h2o-py got an unexpected HTTP status code:
 404 Not Found (method = DELETE; url = http://localhost:54321/3/InitID). 
detailed error messages: DELETE /3/InitID not found
```

Please note I have followed the installation steps in this link [Use H2O directly from Python](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tibshirani/8/index.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on SO

Comment: Isn't H2O relevant to Data Science? Can you elaborate why my post is off topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have a version mismatch between your h2o python code and your h2o java code.**

If you [download a fresh version of h2o](http://h2o.ai/download/), make sure you also do a pip install with the same version number.  **Don't use a generic pip install... rather specify the url and version explicitly.**

[Download the java package](http://h2o.ai/download/) and start the java jar:
[image]

But then also click the install python link to get the corresponding pip install command:

[image]

Notice that this line needs to match the java version number that you just installed:

```
pip install http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/reltibshirani/8/Python/h2o-3.6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Then try again:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi AN6U5, Thank you for your help. Your suggestion fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> EnvironmentError: Version mismatch. H2O is version 3.2.0.9, but the python package is version 3.6.0.8.

It looks like you have an instance of 3.2.0.9 already running and the Python package, which is 3.6.0.8, is complaining due to incompatibility.

I recommend you kill the current running instance of H2O (the 3.2.0.9 version that you see in the error message) and run the same commands (import h2o, h2o.init) to drive H2O from Python cleanly.